# How to understand the word "free" in this sentence: "a geyser of death blasting mole bodies free of the planet"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-order, word-in-context, understanding

From [A mole of moles](https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/), I meet this sentence:

> Plumes of hot meat and bubbles of trapped gases like methane—along with the air from the lungs of the deceased moles—periodically rise through the mole crust and erupt volcanically from the surface, **a geyser of death blasting mole bodies free of the planet.**

How to understand the emboldened bit? In either ways to break down it, the word *free* seems to be out-of-place:

- a geyser of [(death blasting mole bodies free) of the planet]
- [a geyser of death] blasting [mole bodies free of the planet]

It looks like the word *free* belongs to the phrase *mole bodies free*, but again, what does it mean? It cannot be an suffix like *smoke-free* or *body-free* because it doesn't make any sense to me, plus that in the phrase the word *bodies* is in plural form.

How should I understand this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure is like this: [a geyser (of death)] [blasting [mole bodies] [free of the planet]]

The participle "blasting" modifies "geyser" (or the whole noun phrase "geyser of death"), not "death" by itself.

"Mole bodies" is the object of the participle.

The phrase starting with "free" is, as Alan Carmack says, complement to the object. It explains the result of the blasting: the mole bodies are made free of the planet.

Unfortunately, I don't know the exact conditions when an adjective or adjectival phrase can be used as a complement like this. It depends a lot on the identity of the verb. I think a similar example is the expression "scared senseless," where the adjective "senseless" describes the resulting state of whoever was scared.

Comment: 'Scared senseless' seems like 'shot dead' (which you can read about on ELU) and 'tickled pink'

Answer (score 1):

> a geyser of death blasting mole bodies free of the planet

[a geyser of death] [blasting] [mole bodies] [free] [of the planet]

Compare

[a park ranger] [setting] [baby bears] [free] [from the trap]

*Free* is an adjective that serves as a complement to  'mole bodies'.

See [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/free), definition 2 with examples.

To rewrite the sentence: The mole bodies are blasted free of the planet by the geyser of death

Comment: so in this case, does it mean that the mole bodies are escaped from the planet by the blasting of the geyser of death?

Comment: Yes. Although we don't use *escape* in the passive, so I would say *The mole bodies are blasted free of the planet by the geyser of death*.